# ¿Se puede usar la perífrasis "deber de" en tiempo pasado?

Tags: modismos

Quisiera saber si la estructura "deber de + infinitivo" se puede usar en tiempo pasado, porque he visto muchas frases como la siguiente:

> Debe de ser muy difícil trabajar tanto.

En cambio, no recuerdo haber visto frases como la siguiente:

> ¿Dónde están las llaves? Debí de olvidarlas en casa.

¿Les parece correcta la segunda frase o no? Si no, ¿por qué, y cómo lo dirían?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, es correcto usar el pretérito perfecto simple:

> Debí de olvidarlas en casa.

También puede usarse el pretérito perfecto compuesto:

> He debido de olvidarlas en casa.

Aunque con esta perífrasis es más habitual usar el infinitivo compuesto para formar el pasado:

> Debo de haberlas olvidado en casa.

O bien

> Las debo de haber olvidado en casa.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta!